# Dynamic Variable Name Building, Concatenate

Tags: c++, variables, arduino, concatenation

My question deals with the Topic of how to easy accessing lots of variables with the arduino. I'd like to know if there is a possibility to change variable names dynamically in a loop. My english is not the best, so let me explain with the code I'm dealing with at the moment.

I have a small thermal printer. The printing method comes from a the adafruit thermal-printing-library

```
void Adafruit_Thermal::printBitmap(int w, int h, const uint8_t *bitmap, bool fromProgMem) {
  ...
}
```

And I've created a bitmap font that looks like this:

```
static const uint8_t PROGMEM Char_32[] {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
}; // Char 032 ( )
static const uint8_t PROGMEM Char_33[] {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x2E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
}; // Char 033 (!)
... for each caracter
```

I like to print out letter for letter in this for-loop:

```
for(j = 0; j <= messageLength - 1; j++){  // Go through each character in the message.
  int character = message[j];  // reads and stores the ASCII value of the current Character        
  printer.printBitmap(letter_width, letter_height, Char_XX);  // i like to print the specific character
}
```

Normaly I would take a 2d array and would print like this:

```
static const uint8_t PROGMEM letter_data[][8] =
{
  {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, // Char 032 ( )
  {0x00, 0x00, 0x2E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, // Char 033 (!)
  {0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00} // Char 034 (")
}

for(j = 0; j <= messageLength - 1; j++){    //Go through each character in the message.
  int Character = message[j] - 32;    // first visible ASCIIcharacter '!' is number 33. reads and stores the ASCII value of the current Character we are dealing with and -32 so the char correspnds to our array.
  printer.printBitmap(letter_width, letter_height, letter_data[Character]);
}
```

But, my letters are going to be a lot bigger then 8x8 pixels, and my array gets to big. So is there a possibility to work around this?

Comment: What do you mean by gets too big? Are you running out of memory?

Comment: You need 3 nested loops: row of bitmap / chars in message / column of bitmap.

Comment: Based on your code, it sounds like *"changing variable names"* is the wrong description for your problem, and your problem has more to do with trying to manage memory use, especially with respect to stack use.

Comment: @user3853544 my letters are 136x72px so the corresponding aray has to be array[][1224] and the compiler throws this error `letters.h:7554: error: size of array is too large

 };

 ^`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds from your description that you're running into issues with memory use. The official Arduino documentation indicates that lower-end Arduino boards have [31.5Kb of Flash Memory](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Memory) (32 - 0.5)—or `PROGMEM`, as tagged in your code—and up to 248Kb (256 - 8) in other systems.

Based on your comment, if every single character takes up 1224 bytes of memory (or 1.2Kb), you'll exhaust this limit in 25 characters in the former system (not even enough to cover the alphabet and nothing else!) and 202 characters in the latter.

So this does depend on the exact system you're building for, but it's quite obvious that at the size of characters you're using, you're going to have problems holding it all, even in the larger system (since this memory capacity is going to be shared with other similarly sized structures).

So, the short answer to your problem: You need to compress your data. My advice would be to shrink the amount of data being used per letter (maybe cut the size on both dimensions in half), and then expand it when you write to the output device (i.e. the display device) at runtime.

Comment: thank you for your comment. i thought of that too. at the moment i'm using the ATmega2560 with 256k bytes (of which 8k is used for the bootloader). My font has 101 characters. I would expect that there would be enough space left. If the characters aren't stored in a 2D array the sketch uploads fine. So you are probably right: The sketch cannot compile when the size of the array is to big because the memory is going to be shared.

Comment: but my question is if there is a workaround without creating a smaller font. its a lot of work and the resolution won't be that fine in the end. in scripting languages there is often the possibility to concat variable names. or maybe someone can think of an other solution. i will try if i can break the array into chunks.

Comment: it worked. i splitted the large array into four smaller arrays and the sketch uploads fine.

Comment: i first thought it worked, because the sketch compiled and uploaded fine. but i hadn't used one of the array in my code. if i include one of the smaller partial-arrays in my programm i get the same error.

Comment: @EEPROM I noticed that your error message occurred at line 7554. Bear in mind that the Flash Memory is also used to store the program itself. My calculations were based on a program that contains those letters and basically nothing else at all. If your program is substantial (and it appears to be) you're going to have less room than you expect. I'm assuming the reason you didn't see the error until you actually used the array is that your compiler was optimizing out unused variables.

Comment: 7554 is the last line of the array. thank you for your responses. i'm using an SD-card now for storing the array. an arduino due worked also like a charm.